# Where to look for open source Java libraries?

Tags: java, open-source, github, google-code, sourceforge

I am looking for a Java library to incorporate into a demo web app and have looked on github, Google Code and sourceforge. So far, sourceforge seems to have the biggest selection. Are there any other places to look, or is sourceforge going to be my best bet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/) is also a large source of open source projects. [Here](http://freshmeat.net/tags/java-libraries) is a list of projects tagged as Java libraries.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you should take a look on [Java-Source.net](http://java-source.net/) and [OpenSymphony](http://www.opensymphony.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps instead of just wandering randomly, you could tell us what kind of library you need and listen to recommendations.  That said, obvious sites include [Apache](http://apache.org/), particularly [Jakarta](http://jakarta.apache.org/), and [Savannah](http://savannah.gnu.org/).  Also note that not everything hosted on GitHub is FOSS.

Comment: I did that earlier and people told me I should go and look for myself. I deleted that question and posted this one. I think some people just like to 'question the question' regardless of what it is.

Comment: I'm glad to answer questions like, "Where can I find such-and-such Java Collections" library?". If someone told you to buzz off when you asked a question like that, they were wrong. I think questions like that help you /and/ people that find the thread later. Just sending you off to wander sites doesn't seem that productive though.